# React is rendering md (remarkable) as a string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markdown

Below is a dummied down version of the component I'm pulling into another component.

```
import React from "react"

var Remarkable = require('remarkable');
var md = new Remarkable();

const Info = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="pop">
      <div>
<h1>{props.title}</h1>
{md.render('# Remarkable rulezz!')}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Info;
```

On the page it is currently rendering.

```
(the title passed as props, as a h1, and...)
<h1># Remarkable rulezz!</h1>
```

So it's literally rendering out the whole thing as a string, when I want it to behave like html.

How do I do this? Or have I missed the whole point of md?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you for some reason need to render the html as-is using react you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and wrap the content with any tag (`div` or `span` or something else)

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: md.render('# Remarkable rulezz!') }} />
```

References:

- https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html